# How to clear input values of dynamic form in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

From a parent file and a child component (Popup). i’m creating a simple submit form. Form state is cleared after submission, but inside the Popup form the data still remains.

demo:  https://codesandbox.io/s/f7-popup-bugs-forked-owfhp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+reset+dynamic+input+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: In `handleSubmit` you are first invoking `closePopup` which is doing `setFormValues({ name: "", email: "" });` and immediatly after you are invoking `setFormValues({ ...form });` which is setting the completed form values in.

Comment: The dupe has IDENTICAL title

Comment: @mplungjan I think the duplicate is fine, but the big problem is that there is a logical issue in his code, which is mainly setting the same state value twice in the same callback

Comment: @briosheje so between us wee fixed it

Comment: Sorry guys, i was tried to clear one-per -one field initial state. can you look inside the sandbox now? i just want to clear all my dynamic input values that state created before

Comment: @briosheje try to see now the link, i made a mistake. hope you get my question... thanks